# AJAX url path issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX to call on a Node.js file to send a text message on button press. So when I type node app.js in the terminal the message sends to my phone, however, when I use a jQuery click event in my javascript file, it's no longer sending within the browser. I'm thinking the primary problem is within my index.js file and not the Node.js file, more specific, the actual URL path.

Here's my app.js file that contains the info to send the text message (app.js):

```
var accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
var authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

client.messages.create({
  to: "+1...",
  from: "+1...",
  body: "Testing, testing, testing"
}).then((messsage) => console.log(message.sid));
```

My file that contains Javascript (index.js):

```
$("#buttons").click(function() {
  alert("Clicked.");

  $.ajax({
    url: "/app.js",
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function() {
      alert("testing");
    },
    success: function(result) {
      // $("#result").html(result);
      alert("  sss  ");
    }
  }).error(function() {
    alert("wrong");
  });
});
```

So my primary question is, is the URL suppose to be the location/name of the file you're trying to run? So far that's been my understanding, yet the message isn't being sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't going to work. Your ajax request is going to be looking for a service that speaks http and running environment to execute your code, which you haven't provided.

It's not hard though since you already have Express installed.

Here's a bare-bones node/express setup:

```
var accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
var authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.post('/api', function (req, res) { 
    client.messages.create({
        to: "+1...",
        from: "+1...",
        body: "Testing, testing, testing"
    }).then((messsage) => {
        console.log(message.sid)
        res.send('done!', message.sid )
    });
})

app.listen(8000, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!')
})
```

Now you should be able to access it with something like:

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:8000/api",
// etc.
 })
```

Comment: I'm completely new to AJAX and Node.js so those are currently the only two files that I'm working with. I made the adjustments you recommended which I appreciate, but the console is showing me the error of:  POST http://localhost:8000/api net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Hmm sorry about that @mur7ay. You need to actually have the server app running, maybe that's it. So if the express app is in `app.js` you need to start it up with something like `node ./app.js` so it will be listening for connections.

Comment: Oh, ok. I currently have the root folder that contains index.html, index.js, stylesheets.css, app.js, then an actual folder (named: node_modules) that contains a folder called Twilio and another named express and a file called package.JSON which was installed with express. I'm going to try what you suggested.

Comment: I just wanted to better understand it. Since it's on my local computer, will it function once I load everything up on my hosted GoDaddy server?

Comment: No, it probably won't work on go daddy (although it's been a while since I've looked at their offerings). You need a setup that will allow a long running process because the node/express app is essentially *the* server.  Most people I know are running Node on Heroku or Amazon Web Services, but I'm sure their are others.

Comment: Ahhh, ok... it's starting to make more sense now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you misunderstand what happens when you run the ajax call. Think of it like going to a URL in your browser. If you go to something like localhost:8080/app.js (assuming you have a server running) you will get the *text* you posted for app.js, there is no way for the code to run on the server. 
Instead, you need a server listening for a URL like localhost:8080/runappjs. When the receives this url have the code from app.js run, then return something to the browser. This could be JSON, HTML, or whatever you want and could indicate status.
 
Here is a simple example using [express routing](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html)

```
app.post('/runappjs', function (req, res) {
  ***PUT APPJS CODE HERE FOR SIMPLICITY YOU CAN REFACTOR LATER***
  var accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
  var authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
  var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();

  client.messages.create({
    to: "+1...",
    from: "+1...",
    body: "Testing, testing, testing"
  }).then((messsage) => console.log(message.sid));
    res.send('Got a POST request')
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Karl! I was able to get it to work with Mark_M's solution.